# Wordpress form to ask for repairstatus

Tags: php, wordpress

I am relaunching a site of a friend's IT-Shop. On the old site he has now an form for his customers to ask for the repair status of their broken computer/laptop/smartphone and so on.

The new site is going to be a wordpress site. Now I don't know how to implement that form in wordpress. I know there are several plugins to do contact forms in wordpress, but I need a plugin that checks the entered values in the database, to give it back in the page.

Can I somehow add a new page template with the old code and use it for this site? Should I take the old code or should I use a plugin? Do you know a plugin that could work in that case?

The Code of the old form looks like this:

```
<?php

$rnr = $_POST["rnr"];
$passwd = $_POST["passwd"];
$fehler = "";
$select="";  
$gefunden = 0;

if(($rnr.$passwd) != "")
{
    if($rnr == "")
        $fehler = "Kein Reparaturnummer angegeben";
    if($passwd == "")
        $fehler = "Kein Kennwort angegeben";

    if($fehler == "")
    {
        $knr="";
        $name1buchstabe="";
        $cid = mysql_connect("***", "***", "***") or die("!mysql_connect");
        mysql_select_db("***", $cid) or die("!mysql_select_db");
        $select = "select count(ReNummer) as gefunden from reparatur where ReNummer='".$rnr."' and concat(ReNummer, left(KuName,1), KuNummer)='".$passwd."' "; //???
        $result = @mysql_query($select) or die("!mysql_query\n".$select);

        if($next = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            $gefunden = $next["gefunden"];
        }
        if($gefunden == 0)
        {
            $fehler = "Reparaturnummer oder Kennwort falsch<br>\n";
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
        mysql_close($cid);
    }

}

if($gefunden == 0)
{
    if($fehler != "")
    {
        echo "<font  color='#FF0000'>".$fehler."</font>";
    }
?>

    <br><br>
    <form action="status.php" method="post" >

    <table  !border="1" >


    <tr>
     <td align="right"> Reparaturnummer:</td>
     <td>
    <input type="Text" name="rnr" value="<?php echo $rnr; ?>" size="" maxlength="">
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td align="right"> Kennwort:</td>
     <td>
    <input type="Password" name="passwd" value="<?php echo $passwd; ?>" size="" maxlength="">
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>&nbsp; </td>
     <td align="right"><input type="Submit" name="" value="Anmelden"> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </form>
<?php
}
elseif($gefunden == 1)
{
    $cid = mysql_connect("***", "***", "***") or die("!mysql_connect");
    mysql_select_db("***", $cid) or die("!mysql_select_db");

    $select = "select k.Name, k.Vorname, r.Defektbeschreibung, r.Materialkosten, r.Arbeitskosten, r.Gesamtkosten from kunde k, reparatur r where r.ReNummer='".$rnr."' and k.KuNummer=r.KuNummer";

    $result = @mysql_query($select) or die("!mysql_query\n".$select);
    if($next = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $kVorname= $next["Vorname"];
        $kName = $next["Name"];
        $rDefektbeschreibung = $next["Defektbeschreibung"];
        $rMaterialkosten = $next["Materialkosten"];
        $rArbeitskosten = $next["Arbeitskosten"];
        $rGesamtkosten = $next["Gesamtkosten"];

        if($rDefektbeschreibung != "")
            $rDefektbeschreibung = "<u>Defektbeschreibung:</u> ".$rDefektbeschreibung."<br><br>\n";

        if($rMaterialkosten != "0")
            $rMaterialkosten = "<u>Materialkosten:</u> ".number_format($rMaterialkosten,2, ",", ".")." &euro;<br><br>\n";
        else
            $rMaterialkosten = "";

        if($rArbeitskosten != "0")
            $rArbeitskosten = "<u>Arbeitskosten:</u> &nbsp;&nbsp;".number_format($rArbeitskosten,2, ",", ".")." &euro;<br><br>\n";
        else
            $rArbeitskosten = "";


        if($rGesamtkosten != "0")
            $rGesamtkosten = "<u>Gesamtkosten:</u> ".number_format($rGesamtkosten,2, ",", ".")." &euro;<br><br>\n";
        else
            $rGesamtkosten = "";


    }
    mysql_free_result($result);

    $select = "select date_format(Datum, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i') as DDatum, MA, Status, Bemerkung from rep_status where ReNummer='".$rnr."' order by Datum desc";

    $result = @mysql_query($select) or die("!mysql_query\n".$select);

    echo $kVorname." ".$kName."<br>\n";
    echo "Reparaturnummer: ".$rnr."<br><br>\n";
    echo $rDefektbeschreibung;
    echo $rMaterialkosten;
    echo $rArbeitskosten;
    echo $rGesamtkosten;

    echo "<hr noshade size='1'>\n";
    echo "<table  !border='1' >\n";

    while($next = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<tr><td> <b>".$next["DDatum"]."</b> </td><td> &nbsp;".$next["Status"]." </td> </tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($cid);

}

?>
```

Thank you for you answers!

Greetings,
Linda

Comment: Gravity forms is a premium plugin that will allow you to do conditional fields and is probably the most versatile form plug in out there.we use it exclusively in our dev shop & has been a great asset for us

Comment: And you are sure that this plugin will help me/solve this problem? I just don't want to buy something to see that it's not what i was looking for... How is the support of that plugin? Are they fast in responding?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it is free to try. The add-ons that extend some capabilities, require a developers license. For your situation, it seems easier to just build a standard html form that queries the db and AJAXs the content back into the page. You probably don't need a contact form to do what you're wanting

Comment: Yeah, I think so, too... Do you maybe know how to do that standard site in wordpress?

Comment: I do. I can send you a little plugin that I wrote that I use to quickly add some ajax functionality to wordpress. It basically just gives you a starting place as far as enqueueing the scripts, and the basic js & php. You'd still need to create the form on your page, add in the db query in the php, & edit the js for your validation & success/error messages. Like I said, it's a starting place, but you're welcome to it. Just let me know

Answer (score 0):

You could do this manually like in the existing code you provided along with your question. You could simply create a new WordPress template for the job and paste your code.

But - judging from what I can see - you're code looks pretty bad. Spaghetti code, no prepared statements and other things that might've been state of the art 15 years ago but should not be used today.

You can use NinjaForms (http://docs.ninjaforms.com/category/25-actions). It's a free WordPress-Plugin. Using actions you can hook into pretty much every aspect of the form submission and check the entered values for validty. If you want to add logic beyond this (conditionally show or hide fields) you can buy a plugin or simply use jQuery if you're on a tight budget.

If money is not a problem go for GravityForms. Compared to other plugins it's rather cost-intensive but provides the most features.